# ExtJS 7.2 chart missing markers

Tags: extjs

For whatever reason, my line series is not generating markers in ExtJS 7.2.
Following is my code, and image of current output is attached.

```
    new Ext.chart.series.Line({
        axis: 'left',
        //smooth: true,
        fill:false,
        xField: 'name',
        yField: 'aggregate',
        style: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            stroke: '#30BDA7',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        },
        title: 'Aggregate Count',
        tooltip:{
            trackMouse:true,
            titleAlign:'center',
            renderer: function(toolTip, record, ctx) {
                toolTip.setHtml(record.get(ctx.field));
            }
        },
        marker: {
           type: 'path',
           path: ['M', - 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, - 4, 'Z'],
           stroke: '#30BDA7',
           //'stroke-width':5,
           lineWidth: 2,
           fill: 'black'
        },
        showMarkers:true,
        selectionTolerance:20
    })
```

[image: Missing line markers]

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of searching I discovered that I had to addd a series to the chart using lazy rendering.  To fix the code I simply removed the explicit declaration  "new Ext.chart.series.Line" and converted it to "type:'line'". Everything magically worked after that.  The reason for this is that the series will not generate an overlay surface when explicitly defined.

```
{
    type:'line'
    axis: 'left',
    //smooth: true,
    fill:false,
    xField: 'name',
    yField: 'aggregate',
    style: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        stroke: '#30BDA7',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    },
    title: 'Aggregate Count',
    tooltip:{
        trackMouse:true,
        titleAlign:'center',
        renderer: function(toolTip, record, ctx) {
            toolTip.setHtml(record.get(ctx.field));
        }
    },
    marker: {
       type: 'path',
       path: ['M', - 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, - 4, 'Z'],
       stroke: '#30BDA7',
       //'stroke-width':5,
       lineWidth: 2,
       fill: 'black'
    },
    showMarkers:true,
    selectionTolerance:20
}
```